# How do frogs and fish rain?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, atmospheric-science, weather, lift

I saw a documentary about the rain of frogs and fish in certain areas due to water sprouts sucking them up and causing rain of frogs and fish (pretty large ones) hundreds of miles away. But how is it possible that frogs and fish can be transported such large distances without them falling immediately even in calm weathers?

Comment: Can you add a link to this?

Comment: It was on TV @Chair

Comment: Sounds like there's [currently no scientific consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_animals) on these.

Comment: I'm voting down because I see no direct question about physics.

Comment: @user190081 How is this not a question about physics. It involves gravity, buoyancy, fluid mechanics etc. If you can help please help but dont downvote.

Comment: @Mechanic7 Under that criteria, any observation (or assumption, as is the case of this question) that you can make about the world qualifies as a 'question about physics' as everything in the natural world can be ultimately explained with some physics concept. I find your question unfocused, you are not asking about a particular mechanism or phenomenon, which is why I'm downvoting.

Comment: @user190081 im asking about the natural phenomenon behind this seemingly miraculous event. Im not superstitious and I dont want to leave this question as something which I cannot comprehend. You can help by explaining the phenomenon. Your downvote doesn't help in any way. I didnt ask about a homework problem or some off topic biology problem or an opinion based problem.

Comment: Waterspouts and calm weather really don't seem compatible. Why do you say "calm weather"?

Comment: @PeterShor I mean water sprouts pick them up and after miles of relatively calm weather, then rain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The wiki article is explanatory:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_animals)

> Raining animals is a rare meteorological phenomenon in which flightless animals fall from the sky. Such occurrences have been reported in many countries throughout history. One hypothesis is that tornadic waterspouts sometimes pick up creatures such as fish or frogs, and carry them for up to several miles. However, this aspect of the phenomenon has never been witnessed by scientists.

.......

> A current scientific hypothesis involves tornadic waterspouts: a tornado that forms over the water. Under this hypothesis, a tornadic waterspout transports animals to relatively high altitudes, carrying them over large distances. This hypothesis appears supported by the type of animals in these rains: small and light, usually aquatic, and by the suggestion that the rain of animals is often preceded by a storm. However, the theory does not account for how all the animals involved in each individual incident would be from only one species, and not a group of similarly-sized animals from a single area.

It would be a turbulance siphoning water up, [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5BGql-Lzl8) at 0.45 seconds for the power involved.  The turbulance does not end at the level of the clouds, just angular momentum conservations would ensure that, so small animals could be carried up with the water  and follow the turbulance within the cloud, until it slowly dissipates and they cannot stay up any longer due to their unsupported weight.

[Here  is a video](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/raining-fish-video-sri-lanka-3507877) of fallen live fish, at 1.07 min.

The objection of the wiki quote "the theory does not account for how all the animals involved in each individual incident would be from only one species" is not really serious, imo, as fish notoriously swim in schools , it is finding them isolated that is unusual.

Of course since there is no recorded *with measurements*  at input and recorded in the cloud such occurrence, everything is a hypothesis.